# Use Razor Page handler as image source

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following handler

```
public IActionResult OnGetCaptchaImage()
    {
        const int numCaptchaCharactersInCode = 6;
        const int charWidth = 20;
        const int width = numCaptchaCharactersInCode * charWidth;
        const int height = 40;
        var captchaCode = Captcha.GenerateCaptchaCode(numCaptchaCharactersInCode);
        var result = Captcha.GenerateCaptchaImage(width, height, captchaCode);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaptchaCode", result.CaptchaCode);
        Stream s = new MemoryStream(result.CaptchaByteData);
        return new FileStreamResult(s, "image/png");
    }
```

and I need to display the resulting image here

```
<img id="img-captcha" src="???" alt="Captcha Image"/>
```

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is

```
<img id="img-captcha" src="Create?handler=CaptchaImage" alt="Captcha Image"/>
```

it follows the example here:

https://codeshorts.com/ASP-NET-CORE-Razor-Pages-Return-a-image-from-a-byte-array

Comment: The other examples show that what you posted works with controllers, but not razor pages. I tried it anyway, and the method was not found. I am new to Razor Pages and struggling with this coming from an MVC background.

Comment: One option would be to implement a custom `IFileProvider` for static files, but probably there is a more elegant solution. I am learning Razor pages myself and overlooked the tag, sorry.

Comment: It's definitely different... I'm trying to resist adding a WebAPI to the project just to support various services such as this, but maybe that's where I'll end up.

Comment: This link shows how it can be done: https://codeshorts.com/ASP-NET-CORE-Razor-Pages-Return-a-image-from-a-byte-array

Comment: I Googled endlessly and didn't find that... thank you very much. For anyone who comes after... all I changed was this: src="Create?handler=CaptchaImage". Worked perfectly.